# event propagation in IE

Tags: javascript

In a simple HTML page, for the below code,

```
<ul>
        <li id='testlist' style='border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;width:100px;height:100px;' onkeydown= "alert('kd');" onkeypress="alert('kp');" tabindex='0'>
            Click me
         </li>
</ul>
```

when I press "ENTER" (with focus on the li element), first "kd" pops up and then "kp" popups. From this I infer that normally onKeyDown() executes first followed by onKeyPress(). Which means event propagation from key down to key press happens normally.

But in my project, for the same code,this flow isn't happening. The flow stops with "kd".

What could be possible reasons that the event propagation is stopping with onKeyDown() and not moving to onKeyPress()

My doubt is what could be the possible ways to achieve this scenario. ie. Stopping event propagation. One possibility i got to know is "stopPropagation". But i haven't used it in my code anywhere. Is there any other possibility to achieve the same.

Comment: You've sort of answered your own question, in that you've shown that this code works, so it must be some code elsewhere in your project preventing it.  Without seeing the code, it's hard to say.

Comment: I completely agree with you. My doubt is what could be the possible ways to achieve this scenario. ie. Stopping event propagation. One possibility i got to know was, "stopPropagation". But i haven't used it in my code anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

These events are not been propagated. They are TWO separated events.

`keyPress` is one event and `keyDown` is another event.

There is no way you could stop propagating `keyPress` from a `keyDown` event (without custom code with flags or something else).

Event propagation happens from a child element to a parent element. Not from one eventType to another eventType.

Comment: Couldn't you brief on possible customization to make it happen if you are aware.